# Running docker container with SSH from cygwin display not working

Tags: docker, x11, boot2docker, x11-forwarding

I'm running a docker toolbox installed on my Windows 7 computer, I'm trying to access the docker from outside (win desktop) so I can get a GUI App working (let say we will test with Firefox)
As you all know, docker does not come with Server X, so I've found the solution is to install xcygwin to perform X11 tasks and then run the container via ssh so it could be displayed on my Windows.

The problem is I cant set the display right, I do:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

And tried few other options like exporting to the IP of the host, exporting to localhost etc.. then I SSH into my docker by running:

```
docker-machine ssh default -X
```

(the -X supposed to activate the x11 forwarding if I'm not wrong)

Now, I get into my docker, so simply I try to run my magic firefox container by running something like this:

```
docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY devurandom/firefox
```

I get the expected Error: `cannot open display`.

Right! I didnt set the display in my docker! so I did :

```
DOCKER=0.0
```

I get `Cannot open display: 0.0`!

I also tried this one which I couldnt figure where the Path is comming from but well..

```
docker run -ti  -v /tmp/serverX:/tmp/ServerX -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY ...
```

No luck, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is the X server active and running in windows? What DISPLAY is it configured to use?

Comment: Yes I forget to mention that, its active and working: ive used startx -listen tcp,
And how to know which display? I think its the default one which is :0 or my local one, dont know if I answer ur question right ..

Comment: Are you sure X11 is running on the host (windows) computer? It should be "startxwin" AFAIK.

Comment: Well I tried both actualy startxwin et startx

Comment: What if you do `docker ssh -X -Y` to get into the machine?

Comment: I think u r right, my xserver was running correctly but now i Re-checked there's some error message I think I've did something wrong:

Comment: xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down winClipboardProc - winClipboardFlushWindowsMessageQueue trapped WM_QUIT message, exiting main loop.
winClipboardProc - XDestroyWindow succeeded.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - Fatal error 1 on xcb connection
winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Comment: when I run just startxwin without params, I dont get this error! But my container still not working